# All Angular projects have the same problem with component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Been following some Angular 7 project videos on YouTube but get caught out by the basic stage of trying to pass a name from `component.ts` to the `component.html`.

Current output with current code is `"Hello"` minus the name - no error messages.

APP.COMPONENT.TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
name:string = 'Brad';
}
```

APP.COMPONENT.HTML:

```html
  <div>
  <h1>Hello {{ name | uppercase }} </h1>
  {{ 1 + 1 }}
  </div>
```

Comment: any console error in your dev tools?

Comment: can you please try running the app like this : ng-serve —aot. (That’s a double -) and tell me what you get

Comment: when using ng-serve --aot:

ERROR in src/app/app.component.html(2,7): : Property 'name' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please import `CommonModule` from `@angular/common`. You are using `uppercase` which is provided by the `CommonModule`.